# Width of absolutely positioned elements is not respected

Tags: html, css, position

I want to do some text replacement, where one substring fades in and the other fades out. My thinking is to have to "overlapping" spans, and animate the `opacity`.

```html
    <p>
      This is the 
      <span style="position: relative;">
        <span style="position: absolute;">wrong</span>
        <span style="position: absolute;" class="hidden">correct</span>
      </span> 
      answer.
    </p>
```

I expected `wrong` and `correct` to overlap and the surrounding `<span>` element to have the width of the longest word. But the surrounding element gets a width of 0, causing the word `answer` to overlap as well.

Is there a workaround to respect the width of absolutely positioned elements? Assume them to have dynamic content, so you cannot be certain which one will be longest.

edit: After some looking around, this seems to be the case: the span with `position: relative` has no content, so it will have no width. The inner spans will automatically become blocks, because they are positioned absolutely. You could give them a width, but that will not impact the outer span. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the container span an inline-flex, direction column

This will stack vertically the inner spans

then make those height 0, so that they share the same vertical position:

```css
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>
      This is the 
      <span class="container">
        <span class="item">wrong</span>
        <span class="item hidden">correct long</span>
      </span> 
      answer.
    </p>
```

Comment: Really elegant. Never thought of applying `inline-flex` here.

Answer (score 2):

Using `position: absolute` removes an element from the normal document flow. The element will no longer effect the layout of other elements in the document. The element will take up no vertical or horizontal space which is what you are seeing when the text node `answer` is overlaid by the absolutely positioned elements.

One solution to this would be to only use `position: absolute` on the shortest of the two `span`s. You could then hide or show the correct `span` by changing the opacity of the elements:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.result-wrap');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.classList.toggle('show-negative');
    el.classList.toggle('show-positive');
});
```

```css
.result-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.result {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.result-negative {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.show-negative .result-negative,
.show-positive .result-positive{
  opacity: 1;
}

.show-negative .result-positive
.show-positive .result-negative{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is the 
  <span class="result-wrap show-positive">
    <span class="result result-negative">wrong</span>
    <span class="result result-positive">correct</span>
  </span> 
  answer.
</p>

<button type="button">
Toggle result
</button>
```

Comment: I had thought of this, but with dynamic content you can never be sure which is the longer of the two. You could count the string length, but that is not reliable for anything but monospace fonts. Think of 'lilly' vs 'wowy'

Comment: Hi Roy. You didn't mention dynamic content in your question. This is a vital piece of information that really should have been included.

Comment: I will update the question to reflect that. The code example was deliberately simplified, but I agree it should have been mentioned. Not that I see any obvious solution with the information at hand

Answer (score 0):

Updated snippet

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
correct = document.querySelector('.correct'),
wrong = document.querySelector('.wrong'),
cW = correct.offsetWidth,
wW = wrong.offsetWidth,
btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

correct.style.position = "absolute";
correct.style.top = 0;
wrong.style.position = "absolute";
wrong.style.top = 0;

function checklonger () {
if (el.classList.contains('show-correct')) {
     el.style.width= cW + 'px';
}
else {
     el.style.width= wW + 'px';
}
}
checklonger ();

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   el.classList.toggle('show-correct');
   el.classList.toggle('show-wrong');
   checklonger();
});
```

```css
p {
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease;

}
.correct, .wrong {
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.show-correct .correct, .show-wrong .wrong  {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<p>
      This is the
      <span class='wrapper show-correct'>
        <span class="correct">correct</span>
        <span class="wrong">wrong </span>

      </span> 
    answer
    </p>

<button class="btn">toggle</button>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are spacing it out manually. That will not work with any kind of dynamic content.

Comment: Hi Roy, I thought you have predefined strings that you'll be using inside the elements. Even though if you make it dynamic you would possibly get an animation flick due to the difference between shorter and longer strings. I guess the best practice would be initially keeping the element’s position property as ’relative’ and storing both ’with’ value and then changing the position :’absolute’  with:storedwith

Comment: I will give it a try, but would you agree that the answer by @vals is the most elegant solution?

Comment: Hi @RoyPrins, It's an excellent solution to both elements to share the same place by CSS but doesn't solve the issue of getting a gap due to differences between both elements.
You'll need Js to redefine those with, later on, to animate them without getting an extra gap due to the longer one.

Comment: The gap is not an issue but a feature in my case. For my application, there will never be a big gap and any resizing will distract from the actual replacement. Glad to have your solution as well though.